# Bootstrap 4 navi-bar breakpoint

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello guys im trying to make my navigation bar responsive it is but when i decrease the resolution my navbar is under 'COMPANY' i've seen some posts but none of them did work so i want to ask if someone knows how to fix this?

My code:

```
 <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="comp navbar-brand">COMPANY</a>
        </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
        <ul class="navi nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
        <center><button type="button" class="learn">Learn more</button></center>
        <center><p class="how">How did i get started?</p></center>
        <center><p class="date">2016-2017</p></center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.container` or `.container-fluid` for your navbar to wrap contents and house Bootstrap grid system. See [Containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) and [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) sections for details.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <ul class="navi nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

To control point of the navbar collapsing, use `@grid-float-breakpoint` and `@grid-float-breakpoint-max` LESS variables (see [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) section). Also you can set custom values for [Media queries breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints). It is possible to get your own version of Bootstrap using [customization](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) tool.

Comment: I did it but when i try

Comment: <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm">

Comment: @Choori02, if you push *Run code snippet* button, then you will have seen the navar with collapsed menu items. If you push *Full page* link, then you will have seen "desktop" version of the navbar. What is your trouble?

Comment: I have a responsive navbar but when im decreasing the resolution my navbar is under my name and my question is if i can make a custom breakpoint to choose when the icon-bars needs to be shown

Comment: Oh, yes.. you need to edit [@media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries). See also `@grid-float-breakpoint` parameter.

Comment: Could you maybe help me with that?

Comment: You could use [customized version](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) of Bootstrap. Set custom value for `@grid-float-breakpoint` parameter in [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) section.

Comment: How does that @grid-float-breakpoint works? Like (@)media (@grid-float-breakpoint: 1024px) {
.data-toggle
}
?

Comment: `@grid-float-breakpoint` set the point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed. `@grid-float-breakpoint-max` set the point at which the navbar begins collapsing. Use values in CSS Units (800px for example) or another LESS variables (`@screen-md` for example) to set it.